# Unable to run rails application on puma using ssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, puma

I'm trying to run my rails app on puma in development environment on windows box. Without ssl the application works fine..

But when I try to configure ssl for puma, nothing happens. No error is generated in the log and the web page (https://localhost:3000/) says Secure Connection Failed. Below is the output from command line that shows the server started but nothing happened after that..

```
E:\ap01\dev\rmmi>foreman start -p 3000
17:19:31 web.1  | started with pid 3016
17:19:34 web.1  | *** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
17:19:34 web.1  | *** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart  unavailable!
17:19:34 web.1  | *** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
17:19:34 web.1  | Puma starting in single mode...
17:19:34 web.1  | * Version 2.11.2 (ruby 2.0.0-p353), codename: Intrepid Squirrel
17:19:34 web.1  | * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
17:19:34 web.1  | * Environment: development
17:19:36 web.1  | * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
17:19:36 web.1  | * Listening on ssl://127.0.0.1:3000?cert=E:/ap01/OpenSSL-Win32/bin/server.crt&key=E:/ap01/OpenSSL-Win32/bin/server.key
17:19:36 web.1  | Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

My config/puma.rb file is given below -

```
path_to_key="E:/ap01/OpenSSL-Win32/bin/server.key"
path_to_cert="E:/ap01/OpenSSL-Win32/bin/server.crt"
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT'] || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'
ssl_bind '127.0.0.1', '3000', { key: path_to_key, cert: path_to_cert }
on_worker_boot do

  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] ||
                Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['pool'] = ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

The profile for foreman is given below -

```
 web: bundle exec puma -p $PORT -C config/puma.rb
```

I've also set config.force_ssl = true in my apps config/application.rb file.

Could you please advise what I'm missing here or doing incorrectly ?. Any pointers will be appreciated

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything wrong. The browser doesn't trust your local certificate with your localhost, so it will give you a warning.

But you can bypass it using the "Advanced" option on the page (left side bottom) and click proceed to view the ssl version of your application.